# How to merge two google sheets like a set?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know my question is little weird but please help me.

I am having two sheets in which there are 4 columns (District, School, Student, Marks) in both. And both are **sorted on the basis of district>school>student>marks*

So in sheet1 there are 4000 students marks & in sheet2 there are marks of 2000 students in which some are new students and **some are old studens which are present in sheet1 but they got updated marks in sheet2**

so now what I want is how to merge those sheets so that I get new sheet **which should be sorted and with all new students and with updated marks ??**

I have one approach but I don't know how to implement this-

.    get second sheet then take first sheet and then add those rows only which district, school, student is not in second. So by this only data which is not updated(not present is sheet2) will be added in sheet2. And then sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function updateMarks() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//old marks
  const rg1=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,sh1.getLastColumn());
  var vs1=rg1.getValues();
  var js1=vs1.map(function(r,i){return r[0]+r[1]+r[2];})
  const sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//updated marks
  const rg2=sh2.getRange(2,1,sh2.getLastRow()-1,sh2.getLastColumn());
  var vs2=rg2.getValues(); 
  const sh3=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');//combined marks
  sh3.clear();//clear sheet everytime
  sh3.appendRow(['District','School','Student','Marks']);//add headers
  vs2.forEach(function(r,i){
    let idx=js1.indexOf(r[0]+r[1]+r[2]);
    if(idx>-1) {
      vs1[idx]=r;
    }else{
      vs1.push(r);
    }
  });
  const rg3=sh3.getRange(2,1,vs1.length,vs1[0].length);
  rg3.setValues(vs1).sort([{column:1,ascending:true},{column:2,ascending:true},{column:3,ascending:true},{column:4,ascending:true}]);
}
```

Sheet3 is the output sheet

Comment: Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. (line 4, file "Code")

Comment: I have data in sheet1 but still it is throwing this error please help.

Comment: I wonder perhaps your sheet time has a space in it where is incorrect somehow

Comment: Thank You So Much. I was trying this function on diffrent files called sheet1, sheet2, sheet3.

Comment: Sheet1,Sheet2 and Sheet3 are not file names there sheet names the filename is the name of the Spreadsheet